# Git Source Control Provider hotkeys

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) extension for Visual Studio 2010, and I'd like to set a hotkey for Commit, but I can't make it work. I'd like to define a keyboard shortcut for whatever command is run by right-clicking anywhere in my solution, selecting "Git->Commit" (the one with the cow icon, not the one provided by TortoiseGit).

I've set a hotkey for GitPlugin.Connect.GitExtensionsCommit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), to be used globally (yes, I had to disable some other hotkey settings that used Ctrl+G), but whenever I use it I get an error message saying that the command is not currently available.

How do I set hotkeys for the Git Source Control Provider?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this, I was able to get it working.

I configured Ctrl+\, Ctrl+K to be the shortcut (but you can set your own as long as there are no conflicts).

After that, if you select any project/file node and hit the shortcut, it'll trigger the commit.

The *catch* here is that you have to *select* a `project` or `file` in `solution explorer` which makes sense because otherwise, the provider doesn't know what to commit.