# Why Visual Studio's custom hotkey for GitExtensions resets after restart?

Tags: visual-studio, git, hotkeys, git-extensions

I am using GitExtensions version 2.26 Visual Studio extension they comes with. I tried to assign custom keyboard hotkey to commit command like this:

[image]

And everything works great until I will restart Visual Studio. After that hotkey gets magically un-assigned. Everything works if I select any other command, not from the **GitPlugin.*** group. Maybe somebody faced the same problem and found a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676294/git-source-control-provider-hotkeys didn't help in this case?

Comment: nope, I'm not using this provider.

Comment: Considering there is no 2.26 tag in the sources (https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/tags), could you check if the issue persist when downgrading to 2.25 (which is listed in the download page: http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/downloads/list)?

Comment: ok, I will try to downgrade today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could grab the pull request [added access keys to VS plugin menu items](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/pull/782) and build your own copy of the extension. After you copy the files from **GitExtensions\GitPlugin\bin** into **Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins**, you will get <strike>accelerator</strike> access keys for the Git menu. This will allow, for example, you to access **Commit** with **Alt+G, C**.

Comment: I should have said "access keys". (I updated my answer accordingly.) These are the Alt+... keys for menus and other controls. Background is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511502.aspx#accessKeys